# Conditionally Formatting a Custom Image in Excel

Tags: excel, formatting

I want to create an Excel Sheet that takes values as seen below

[image]

And turns them into an image like this with the colors of the spaces being the colors of the conditional formatting as seen above. Then I want them to color in their assigned spaces "Position"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you have got the spreadsheet set up with that image as shapes already, you could write a simple VBA macro to update the colours of the shapes to match colours of cells. Give each shape a unique name by clicking on it then changing its name in the top left (to the left of the formula bar).

Within your macro, you can use the code `COLOUR = Range("cell").DisplayFormat.Interior.Color` to get the colours of the conditionally formatted cells, and then select a shape using `ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Shape Name")).Select`, then change the colour of the selected shape using:

```
With Selection.ShapeRange.Fill
    .ForeColor.RGB = COLOUR
End With
```

Loop through this however many times you need, targeting different cells each time. You could name your shapes sequentially ("Shape1","Shape2" ...) and use concattenation to do this loop: `Name = "Shape"&i` where i is the current loop iteration.